# Grub menu not showing after exiting BIOS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, bios

So I've dual booted Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 on a UEFI system. So far I've been able to switch OSs from the grub menu at the boot screen, which shows entries for both. Recently, I  tried to run android emulator, Genymotion specifically, in Ubuntu. After all was done, I needed to enable Intel Virtuialization Technology from my BIOS, which I did. But after saving my changes and exiting BIOS, my laptop now boots straight into Windows 8.1 without showing the grub menu.

I know I can get the grub menu back if I go on and re-install Ubuntu again, but I really don't want to go down that path.

My boot mode is set to UEFI, and changing it to legacy mode did not bring the grub menu back. My windows bootloader and grub are installed on seperate partitions, if that helps.

So, what am I missing here? Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is similar to many others that have been reported here. See:

- [Ubuntu 14.04 not booting before Windows 8.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464021/ubuntu-14-04-not-booting-before-windows-8-1)
- [Ubuntu 13.04 on UEFI system with Windows Boot Manager as the main loader](https://askubuntu.com/questions/340328/ubuntu-13-04-on-uefi-system-with-windows-boot-manager-as-the-main-loader)
- [Can't boot into Ubuntu after Windows 8.1 upgrade, boot-repair doesn't fix it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/392959/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-after-windows-8-1-upgrade-boot-repair-doesnt-fix-it)

Basically, you should be able to fix the problem using `bcdedit` in Windows, by running Boot Repair from a Linux emergency disk, or by installing rEFInd. (Those are just three relatively easy fixes; there are literally dozens of other ways to fix the problem.)